# Mutual SSL Using HttpClient

Tags: java, ssl, https, httpclient

I am trying to setup 2 - way SSL between client and server using HttpClient 4.3.3 library  for a WebApp to communicate with a server component.

I have the client / server commuicating successfully over SSL in what I believe looks to be one-way SSL in that the CA hierarchy is not being strictly validated from what I can see, or maybe HttpClient is hiding all the details. It also seems quite difficult to get the peer certificate chain, this seems to be accessible through SSLSession object which would be present in strict JSSE interaction but HttpClient abstracts away from and does not seem possible to access?

Looking at the debug SSL logging it all seems to be fine, I guess i just wanted to confirm that 2 way SSL is happening even if it is happening within HttpClient.

Also, the TrustStrategy only seems to access the client Certificate chain and regardless of true or false returned for 'isTrusted' never seems to behave differently.

TLDR; is this 2 way SSL, if not what needs to change? How does one get access to peer certificate chain using HttpClient? Does the TrustStrategy actually do anything?

This is my code thus far which works with the server which I know to be running SSL:

```
try{
        KeyStore trustStore  = KeyStore.getInstance(keystoreType, keystoreProvider);
        FileInputStream instream = new FileInputStream(new File("/path/to/keystore"));
        try {
            trustStore.load(instream,keystorePassword.toCharArray());
        } finally {
            instream.close();
        }

        //establish trust strategy
        TrustStrategy trustStrategy = new TrustStrategy() {
            @Override
            public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {
                for(X509Certificate cert : x509Certificates){
                    System.out.println("cert = " + cert);
                }
                return true;
            }
        };


        SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom().loadKeyMaterial(trustStore, keystorePassword.toCharArray())
                .loadTrustMaterial(trustStore, trustStrategy).build();

        // Allow TLSv1 protocol only
        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                sslcontext,
                new String[] { "TLSv1" },
                null,
                SSLConnectionSocketFactory.STRICT_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
                .build();
        try {

            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(existingSSLServerURL);
            HttpEntity requestEntity = new ByteArrayEntity(sampleAuthenticationForSSL.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            post.setEntity(requestEntity);
            System.out.println("executing request" + post.getRequestLine());

            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(post);
            try {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
                System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
                if (entity != null) {
                    System.out.println("Response content length: " + entity.getContentLength());
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()));
                    String inputline = null;
                    while((inputline = in.readLine()) != null){
                        System.out.println(inputline);
                    }
                }
                EntityUtils.consume(entity);
            } finally {
                response.close();
            }
        } finally {
            httpclient.close();
        }



    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        fail();
    }
```

Comment: Why not use [AuthSSLProtocolSocketFactory](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpcomponents/oac.hc3x/trunk/src/contrib/org/apache/commons/httpclient/contrib/ssl/AuthSSLProtocolSocketFactory.java?view=markup)?

Comment: AuthSSLProtocolSocketFactory is for the older commons-httpclient library which has passed end-of-life but yes I will try using the older component to see if it works. Surely, there must be a way with the newer HttpClient 4.3.3 library?